# Data filtering using multiple dropdown box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, filtering, dropdownbox

This is about our thesis. my teacher advised me to filter the data from the dropdown list. this is the situation
I have 3 dropdown boxes, they get the data in one table.

```
ex.
Smith,
Jacob,
Clint,
Russel,
Mclemore
```

the system works like this:

If I choose smith in the 1st dropdown box then it must not appear in the 2nd and 3rd dropdown box. can you please help me find what could be the best code for this.

Im using php, javascript and im not good in using jquery and other programming languages because im a newbie. thanks

Comment: Here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BUuZv/2/

Comment: thanks for the info. i hope that this will be the solution to my problem. thanks

Comment: im new to this..i got a problem on the data it display...it still displaying the data from the database.

Comment: @m.qayyum Nice - can you solve the ordering problem when you 'de-select' an option?